How to solve the shap_values for GradientExplainer using TensorFlow?
I am running a Shipping Companies top 5 prediction, based on different inputs, everything runs beside the shap_values = explainer.shap_values(model.inputs, model.output) (GradientExplainer)
# Assemble the model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_loading, input_destination, input_segment, input_numerical], outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
hist = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=val_dataset)
explainer = shap.GradientExplainer(model, background_data)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(data, model.output)

I am expecting shap_values to run. I have passed different things to the shap_values, including lists, np.arrays, pandas dataframes, but I get the same error, zero-dimensionality, or missing list of inputs, or kerastensor is not a list errors go back to themselves, and the re are not enough examples online, there is the example using the mnist dataset but it is a dataset that has already been cleaned and redy to fir ml models.

Please specify exactly (in the question please) what input threw what error (with full error message). Otherwise, it's just guessing.

I believe that the line with the error is the call to shap_values. In the last paragraph, it's not clear when the error message starts and ends. If the error varies according to data's type, then please specify what types you have tried for data?
